# Quantum field Maxwell demons and check valves

Tags: quantum-field-theory, thermodynamics, vacuum, cosmological-inflation

Check valves are pressure-operated mechanical diodes, in the sense that matter currents can only flow in one direction

[image: mechanical check valves]

On the other hand, scalar inflaton fields responsible for.. well.. inflation must have nontrivial mechanical properties, like negative absolute pressure (negative pressure relative to a non-expanding vacuum)

Is there a quantum-field equivalent of a mechanical diode or a Maxwell demon, such that quantum fluctuations of (radiation) pressure in one direction can be absorbed at a higher rate from one direction than the other?